# Convert Bootstrap YAMM3 to WordPress using Menus Metabox

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I seen many similar questions but no solution. I am trying to make yamm3 work with Wordpress.

I know there is plugins but they are extremely bloated.
I think it should be very simple just using a custom metabox.

This example adds a metabox but only allows links.
http://pastebin.com/hj1cxYQg

Here is the basic function:

```
/* Mega Menu */

function mynav_add_custom_box() {
    add_meta_box(
        'add-mynav',
        'Mega Menu',
        'mynav_show_custom_box',
        'nav-menus',
        'side',
        'default');
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'mynav_add_custom_box' );

//display nav menu meta box
function mynav_show_custom_box() {
// code to create mega menu
?>
    <p class="button-controls">
      <span class="add-to-menu">
        <input type="submit" class="button-secondary submit-add-to-menu right" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Add to Menu'); ?>" name="add-custom-menu-item" id="submit-customlinkdiv" />
        <span class="spinner"></span>
      </span>
    </p>
    <?php
}
```

Metabox options:

- The first option I would have would be 'how many columns?' using 
  bootstrap grid system for its width (up to 5).
- The second option, you will choose to add menu item(s)/image(s) in the column(s) or use html w/builtin wp editor.

The li that has the mega menu dropdown should have a wrap div with class 'yamm-content', that is the only thing that makes yamm3 structure different.